# Can't locate WWW/Curl/Easy.pm in @INC (@INC contains

Tags: perl

I am trying to configure perl http api.

When I trying to run the perl script then it gives me error. Also I am not able to figure out how to install WWW/Curl/Easy package.

```
[emg@p1 ~]$ perl -c etc/ebe-http-custom.pl 
Can't locate WWW/Curl/Easy.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/perl-5.12.2-emg/lib/site_perl/5.12.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /opt/perl-5.12.2-emg/lib/site_perl/5.12.2 /opt/perl-5.12.2-emg/lib/5.12.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /opt/perl-5.12.2-emg/lib/5.12.2 .) at /opt/perl-5.12.2-emg/lib/5.12.2/Tumasms.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/perl-5.12.2-emg/lib/5.12.2/Tumasms.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at etc/ebe-http-custom.pl line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at etc/ebe-http-custom.pl line 27.
```

Comment: `sudo cpan WWW::Curl::Easy`. You will need `libcurl` installed.

Comment: i recommend Net::Curl::Easy over WWW::Curl::Easy